# Generate input that would cause collisions using Murmur2 64bit hash function

Tags: c++, hashcode, murmurhash

I am stuck on an assignment that consists in finding a vulnerability in `std::unordered_set` that simply inserts some strings in an `unordered_set<string>` in a cycle:

```
for (const auto& user : users_list) {
    users.insert(user);
}
```

See [full source code](https://pastebin.com/JfrVX0sB) for details.

File compiled on UBUNTU as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall run.cpp -o run
```

The task is to provide an input that would make this program return a non zero status code.

Any ideas where to look? The hint is that there is something with the default hashing function and the fact that the program is compiled on ubuntu.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your professor wants you to find and exploit a hash collision attack. You must generate inputs that all hash to the same value, such that the hash table lookup has to `strcmp` the new value with every value of the set to see if a duplicate exists before inserting.

Your next steps should be to find the hashing algorithm for `std::string` on your system and reverse it so you can generate these inputs with the same hash value.

Alternatively, just brute force it: generate a few million or billion random strings, `std::hash` them and store the strings that map to the same hash value.

On libstc++ HEAD, `std::hash<string>` is defined [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L6764-L6771). It calls [Hash_bytes](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/functional_hash.h#L195-L197), which finally calls the [hash function](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/hash_bytes.cc) is based on [MurmurHashUnaligned2](http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/) with seed 0xc70f6907UL.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Don't know why somebody downvoted.